# How do I merge triangle faces

Tags: geometry

[image: Merging Triangles]

How do I merge these three triangle faces, which are all on the same plane, into a single pentagonal face?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Select the edges and dissolve them:

(Menu) Mesh -> Delete (X) -> Dissolve Edges

Comment: Thanks! Both answers worked

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 5 simple steps:

1. Select all triangles you want to delete.
2. Press `X`.
3. Select `Faces` from the context menu.
4. Now select all the edges of the pentagon you want to fill.
5. Press `F`

Comment: Thanks! Both answers worked :-)

Comment: ah, didn't notice @Jackdaw's, his answer is better and simpler.

Answer (score 1):

- Faces selected, and <kbd>F</kbd>, if well-formed, or:
- Faces selected, and <kbd>X</kbd> > 'Limited Dissolve', allowing you to control by angle, (or other parameters,) or:
- All internal edges selected, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> dissolve..

among others, I'm sure.

Comment: Super simple - thanks!